# Italian phrases, prefixes, or suffixes that have meanings similar to those of the English suffixes "-ish", "-like", and "-ishly"?

Tags: english-comparison, phrase-request, suffix

In English, the suffixes listed above are sometimes appended in informal contexts (often, but not always, with humorous intentions) to create an adjective or adverb form of a noun. Are there any similar things in Italian?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The adverb form does not exist in Italian:
(http://www.morewords.com/most-common-ends-with/ishly/) these English adverbs can be translated by a phrase:

- **-ishly**': '*in modo/una maniera piuttosto* generosa/stupida/passiva/febbrile'

> sometimes appended in informal contexts (often, but not always, with
>   ***humorous intentions***) to create an adjective or adverb form of a *noun*

We must distinguish the suffix appended to a noun: '*sheepish* behaviour' (or: he behaved *sheepishly*) which you can translate with

- **da** : comportamento da pecora', or, (more idiomatically),: 'si è comportato da *pecorone*. You can't say 'pecor-esco'. You can use it also in most occurrences of '-like'
- **'-esco'** is a tricky suffix as it is used regularly with *peoples* (arabesco, barbaresco, romanesco), *persons* (dantesco, petrarchesco), *centuries, years* (trecentesco, quattrocentesco, sessantottesco). It can also be used with adjectives: (avvocatesco, cavalleresco, fiabesco, guerresco, poliziesco, popolaresco) it can be interpreted as a pejorative suffix in: (scimmiesco, animalesco, pazzesco) but , careful, the pejorative register is often only in the original word.

The most frequently used suffix are:

- '**-ile**', 'ino','-evole': (febbrile, 'giovanile' only if this is *referred to a mature person*, canterino, ragionevole, arrendevole, socievole)
- '**eggiante**' translates '-like': (tondeggiante, pianeggiante) and in other contexts takes the meaning of 'imitating', 'after the fashion of' and keeps the hyphen (pop-eggiante, rock-eggiante)
- '**-ale** can also translate '-like' and can have a pejorative connotation: (tono professorale)
- '**iccio**' is the neutral suffix for colour: (gialliccio, rossiccio), not used with all colours
- '**-astro**' can be tricky too, as it is usually pejorative with nouns: (medicastro, giovinastro, poetastro), but *not with all* adjectives: 'sordastro' means 'a little deaf', 'durastro' 'a lot hard': with colour or taste may mean both neutral: 'vague, not defined' and pejorative 'not pleasant': (rossastro, giallastro, biancastro, dolciastro, salmastro)
- -ognolo is used in limited contexts

Most humorous suffixes cannot be transalated by a suffix "this soup is *tomato-ish* = questa minestra **sa di** pomodoro'

Answer (score 8):

As other Romance languages, Italian language is highly inflecting: it has about [80 prefixes and 160 suffixes](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/suffissi_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/). At [this link](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana) you may find an incomplete list (for example it misses suffixes "*-ognolo*", "*-eggiante*", "*-igno*", etc.).

It is hard to determine an equivalent for English "*-like*" or "*-ish*" unless you provide more information: how exactly do you wish to modify the meaning of the noun? It seems that you are looking for suffixes that in Italian are named *"suffissi aggettivali alterativi"* (roughly *"alterative, i.e. modifying adjectival suffixes"*).

For example, for colors you often use the suffix ["*-ognolo*"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ognolo/), so something "*greenish*" would become "*verdognolo*"; something "*yellowish*" would become "*giallognolo*", but it could also be "*giallastro*", using the suffix ["*-astro*"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/astro/) (which may add a pejorative nuance).

A very productive suffix is ["*-oso*"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oso/) which you can use to invent countless neologisms: something "*sugary*" would become "*zuccheroso*".

Another possibility may be ["*-esco*"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esco/): "*animalish*" would be "*animalesco*".

To be more precise I need more details from the question, perhaps some examples.

Comment: I suppose there's no 1:1 correspondence anyway, and the suffixes you report here are the nearest ones, though they may have specific meaning: for instance -astro implies some negative/denigrating feeling.

Comment: I agree: Italian suffixes are used in very specific ways, they modify the noun in their own manner, and they are not necessarily applicable to any word in any context.

Comment: This is a bit belated, but I really appreciate the fact that you took the time to add those links. This is a great answer!